# Assign value to People Picker programatically in Infopath

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

As we can assign any field in infopath form using (Eg:TextBox)

```
    MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//my:RequestedHardware",
 NamespaceManager).SetValue("Test");
```

But when i am assigning the same for the PeoplePicker field it is giving an exception means which we can't add the value like this.
Please suggest how can we programatically do this....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the value ? Contact selector control requires three values to be set as shown below

1. gpManager/Person/DisplayName = PrinciplaInfo/DisplayName
2. gpManager/Person/AccountId = PrinciplaInfo/AccountName
3. gpManager/Person/AccountType = "User"

Make sure you are setting all three values.

Comment: the same way you do it with the textbox in your example. doesn't event require code...